# Disabling the Wordpress search button if no input

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, search, attributes

I want to disable the submit button on a Wordpress search field when the field is empty i.e nothing searched for.

This jQuery should work but it doesn't.

After changing:

`if ($(this).val() == '') {
     empty = true;
 }`

to `empty = false;` it removes the attribute when text is inputted but it doesn't add the attribute back in when all text has been removed.

Any ideas?

```js
(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('#searchbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#searchbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform" class="search-form">
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search tools" class="search-field" maxlength="256">
  <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Search" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Comment: The code in your question works. I would imagine the issue is because when you search the page reloads and the button is disabled again (as that's the default state)

Comment: This is not the wordpress way to add a script.  Also, do you have any plugins that might be acting on this search field?